# Tangent Normal Decomposition of covariant derivative of tensors

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

We know that for a submanifold $S$ in $M$. The covariant derivative of vectors obey the following identities
$$
\nabla_XY=D_XY+K(X,Y)\\
\nabla_XN=-W_N(X)+\nabla^{\perp}_XN
$$
Where $X,Y$ are tangent and $N$ normal to $S$. K(.,.) is the extrinsic curvature. W_N(.) is the shape operator and $\nabla^{\perp}$ is the connection on the normal bundle. Further $K$ and $W$ are related as
$$
g(K(X,Y),N)=g(W_N(X),Y)=g(X,W_N(Y))
$$
Where $g$ and $h$ are the metric and induced metric. My question is whether such decomposition also exists for tensors? . I am interested in a $(0,2)$ tensor $P_{\mu\nu}$. If $X,Y$ and $Z$ are tangent vectors to $S$. Then $P(Y,Z)$ is a scalar. Then it's covariant derivative can be computed as follows
$$
\nabla_X(P(Y,Z))=(\nabla_XP)(Y,Z)+P(D_XY,Z)+P(Y,D_XZ)+P(K(X,Y),Z)+P(Y,K(X,Z))
$$
What I need is the first term in R.H.S. But I am stuck with the L.H.S. $P(Y,Z)$ is a scalar. I don't know how to proceed?

Comment: Yes. It all follows in a straightforward way from the formulas you wrote and the definition of the covariant derivative of a tensor. Try working it out.

Comment: @DeaneYang I have elaborated on my question please check.

Comment: "As I don't want to break $C(Y,Z)$ into its tangent and normal part in a basis"... but what are you hoping for then? The identities you listed is precisely what happens when you "break" a vector field into its normal and tangent components. If you want something similar you have to of course break your tensor into tangential and normal parts.

Comment: @WillieWong I have downgraded the tensor to (0,2). I am bit confused with the scalar

Comment: For a scalar function, $\nabla_X(P(Y,Z)) = D_X(P(Y,Z)) = \iota_X d(P(Y,Z))$. Basically: "all derivations act the same on scalars".

Comment: BTW: as @DeaneYang said, in many textbooks this is how derivations for general rank tensors are defined. You define the action on scalars (picking out the vector field), and then the action on vector fields. Then the action on arbitrary tensors follows from the Leibniz rule and compatibility with contractions. IIRC this is how things are done in Petersen's Riemannian Geometry, and in O'Neill's Semi-Riemannian Geometry.